# Access Behat command line option or flag in context method

Tags: php, bdd, behat

**Is it possible to get the value of a command-line option or see if a command-line flag is set from within a Behat context method?**

I'm using a hook as described [here](http://behat.readthedocs.org/en/v3.0/guides/3.hooks.html) to set the xdebug session cookie before steps. This works fine, but I'd like to be able to control whether the cookie is set from the command-line.

Currently I have something like this (simplified):

```php
/**
 * @BeforeStep
 */
public function xdebugCookie()
{
    $this->getSession()->setCookie('XDEBUG_SESSION', 'PHPSTORM');
}
```

But ideally I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
/**
 * @BeforeStep
 */
public function xdebugCookie()
{
    if ($this->cliFlagSet('xdebug')) { // does this kind of functionality exist?
        $this->getSession()->setCookie('XDEBUG_SESSION', 'PHPSTORM');
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this just to be able te debug tests?

Comment: @gvf yes, this is to debug the app whilst tests are running

Comment: AFAIK what you're asking for doesn't exist. You could wrap bin/behat in a shell command that accepts that flag and initalises the debug flag: export XDEBUG_CONFIG="XDEBUG_SESSION_START=15095"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an environment variable to accomplish the same:

```php
/**
 * @BeforeStep
 */
public function xdebugCookie()
{
    if ('1' === getenv('XDEBUG')) {
        $this->getSession()->setCookie('XDEBUG_SESSION', 'PHPSTORM');
    }
}
```

This way you can define the variable while running behat:

```sh
XDEBUG=1 ./bin/behat
```

You could also export it to make sure all runs enable (or disable) the debugger:

```sh
export XDEBUG=1
./bin/behat
```